# SQL Server 2012 -> CTRL F - Quick Replace Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 I I have a query that uses numbers for my where clause for example:

```
Select *
from abcTable
where code IN (1, 2, 20, 40, 50)
```

Imagine there are lots inside the `IN` criteria, not only does 5 items as in my example.
Now when I run, the column `CODE` in my `abcTable` is a varchar and it complains about the conversion. Fair enough.

Is there a way of quick find and replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) find all numbers and add double codes between the numbers?

I tried using Regular Expressions, Wildcards everything and it just does not work.

At the end I have to go manually and edit that like that:

```
where code IN ('1', '2', '20', '40', '50')
```

Would you know how to best use the Find and Replace for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything to do this really.

I guess a quick and dirty way would be to replace `,` with `', '`

This would give you:

`where code IN (1', '2', '20', '40', '50)`

So you would just need to add the first and very last `'` to your query to give you:

`where code IN ('1', '2', '20', '40', '50')`